# How to connect particles to rigid bodies in LiquidFun?

Tags: physics, box2d, rigidbody, particles, joints

In vanilla Box2D various types of Joints can be used to connect two rigid bodies together. The LiquidFun extension brings the Particle Module, but I was unable to find a way to connect a particle/particle group to a rigid body.

I use LiquidFun to create a "Jelly" elastic rectangle and I would like to connect it to rigid rectangle so that they would move together. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything involving [Fixtures](https://google.github.io/liquidfun/Programmers-Guide/html/md__chapter07__fixtures.html)?

Comment: @Pikalek Well I know you can attach fixture to body. But neither particles nor particle groups are fixtures. I didn't find a way to connect them that way.

Comment: Particles can be collected into a [group](https://google.github.io/liquidfun/Programmers-Guide/html/md__chapter11__particles.html#cdpg), groups have a shape & fixtures can attach shapes to bodies.

Comment: @Pikalek Shapes are just definitions, reusable structs with no other meaning. Fixture has some shape. Particle group has some shape. Shape has no pointer to neither fixture nor particle group. That wouldn't work sadly :/